# azure function app - linux consumption plan - unable to import modules

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

The deployment with vscode run 100% fine,
in the log I see it uses oryx.

header:

```
import datetime
import logging
import adal
import requests
import json
```

I want to upload the code using Azure Pipelines though, for the sake of automation.
Here is my code

```
    steps:
      - bash: |
          if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
          then
              dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
          fi
        displayName: 'Build extensions'
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0  
        displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'  
        inputs:  
          versionSpec: '3.9'
      - bash: |
          python3.9 -m venv worker_venv
          source worker_venv/bin/activate
          pip3.9 install setuptools
          pip3.9 install -r requirements.txt
        displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: "Archive files"
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/functions"
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveType: zip
          archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          replaceExistingArchive: true
      - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        artifact: drop
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
        displayName: 'Deploy functions to Function App'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: Service-Conn
          appType: functionAppLinux
          appName: 'pythontest'
          package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          runtimeStack: 'Python|3.9'
          deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          resourceGroupName: $(resourcegroup_name_app)
```

But I end up with module not found error (in the monitor of function in azure portal).

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adal'.
```

the uploaded zip have site packages
there is no error in pipeline

What am I missing? Any ideas guys?

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, Microsoft will stop support for ADAL library and the recommendation is to move to MSAL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt` is the command you want to run if you need to ship your libraries in the deployment zip file instead of running pip on function app service.

Your pipeline code installed libraries into .venv and function app runtime will not use that folder.

refs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Cpython#build-your-app
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization

Comment: Yes, there is more: you need to follow the folder structure as microsoft wants. Any other - does not work. Also, you need to use absolute paths, and resolve them in python to import. Also you need to put empty ```__init__.py``` file in each package, for azure to consider it worthy of import. I got it to work, but I don't like how "user unfriendly" the setup were.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30588

Comment: Also note that there is now two different programming models for python. V2 is still on preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to run a task to install **pip** in pipeline console. See link below for better clarity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops